# No module named 'timeout_decorator' in drake vibrating_pendulum

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, drake

I tried to run `from underactuated.exercises.pend.test_vibrating_pendulum import TestVibratingPendulum` in `vibrating_pendulum.ipynb` and I got:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'timeout_decorator'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're running the underactuated notebooks on your local machine and did not install the underactuated requirements?

```
pip3 install -r underactuated/requirements.txt
```

will install the `timeout-decorator` package, and any others you're missing.